# How do I use NSSecureCoding to guarantee the content of collection classes?

Tags: objective-c, nscoding, nssecurecoding

I have an object of class `SGBContainer` which has an array named `objects` that contains objects of class `SGBObject`.  Currently, they each implement NSCoding but not NSSecureCoding.  The `-initWithCoder:` for `SGBContainer` looks like this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self)
    {
        _objects = [aCoder decodeObjectForKey:@"objects"];
    }
}
```

I want to switch to using NSSecureCoding, and from what I can tell, it would mean changing the above to this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self)
    {
        _objects = [aCoder decodeObjectOfClass:[NSArray class] forKey:@"objects"];
    }
}
```

...which isn't much of an improvement, as the contents of the array will be instantiated whatever their class.  How do I make sure that the array only contains objects of class `SGBObject` without instantiating them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although it's not at all clear from the documentation (and just sounds like an oddly ungrammatical method name), this is what `-decodeObjectOfClasses:forKey:` does. You'd do something like the following:

```
NSSet *classes = [NSSet setWithObjects:[NSArray class], [SGBObject class], nil];
_objects = [aCoder decodeObjectOfClasses:classes forKey:@"objects"];
```

(Credit where it's due: See [NSSecureCoding trouble with collections of custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376746/nssecurecoding-trouble-with-collections-of-custom-class))

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way of doing this with `NSSecureCoding`, as `NSCoder` isn't collection aware. You have to manually sanitize the array to make sure it contains only objects of type `SGBObject` (which, to be fair, kind of defeats the purpose of `NSSecureCoding`).

An alternative would be to encode and decode your array yourself, instead of relying on `NSCoder` for doing so.

Comment: "NSCoder isn't collection aware" - Thank you so much! I have been stuck on this for a day, and this never ocurred to me.

Answer (score 1):

Sean D.'s answer is correct to unblock the code, but there is one caveat: the foundation does not guarantee the class types inside of the array, IF they are foundation classes. E.g. the following code demonstrates the problem:

```
@implementation Serializable
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
  return [super init];
}
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
}
+ (BOOL)supportsSecureCoding {
  return YES;
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  NSArray *foo = @[ @1, @"Gotcha", [Serializable new] ];
  NSMutableData *archive = [NSMutableData data];
  NSKeyedArchiver *archiver =
      [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:archive];
  archiver.requiresSecureCoding = YES;
  [archiver encodeObject:foo forKey:@"root"];
  [archiver finishEncoding];

  NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = 
     [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:archive];
  unarchiver.requiresSecureCoding = YES;
  NSSet *classes = [NSSet setWithArray:@[ [NSArray class], [Serializable class] ]];
  // Should throw, but it does not.
  NSArray *loaded = [unarchiver decodeObjectOfClasses:classes forKey:NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey];
  if (loaded.count > 2 && ![loaded[0] isKindOfClass:[Serializable class]]) {
    NSLog(@"Successfully performed object substitution attack.");
    NSLog(@"Class: %@", [loaded[0] class]);  // All 3 objects are
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:archivedData];
unarchiver.requiresSecureCoding = YES;
MyClass *myClass = [unarchiver decodeObjectOfClass:[MyClass class] forKey:@"root"];
```

If you don't set `unarchiver.requiresSecureCoding = YES`, then no checks will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Here is **Swift 4.2** version:

Let's assume you have you custom class **CustomClass**. 
Make sure it conforms ***NSSecureCoding*** protocol.

```
class CustomClass: NSObject, NSCopying, NSSecureCoding {
    var longName: String
    var shortName: String

    init(longName: String, shortName: String) {
        self.longName = longName
        self.shortName = shortName
    }

    // MARK: - NSCoding Protocol

    required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let longName = (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "longName") as? String ?? "")
        let shortName = (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "shortName") as? String ?? "")

        self.init(longName: longName, shortName: shortName)
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(self.longName, forKey: "longName")
        aCoder.encode(self.shortName, forKey: "shortName")
    }

    // MARK: - NSSecureCoding Protocol

    static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true

    // MARK: - NSCopying Protocol

    func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        return CustomClass(longName: self.longName, shortName: self.shortName)
    }
}
```

First you need to convert your objects array to the binary data and archive it:

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
let customObjectsData = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: customObjectsArray, requiringSecureCoding: true)
userDefaults.set(customObjectsData, forKey: USER_DEFAULTS_DATA_KEY)
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

After this you are able to read the data from the **UserDefaults** and unarchive it:

```
if let customObjectsData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: USER_DEFAULTS_DATA_KEY) {
    if let customObjects = (try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [NSArray.self, CustomObject.self], from: customObjectsData)) as? [CustomObject] {
        // your code
    }
}
```